# Cobalt crash at start up when use system_gles2

Tags: cobalt

After setting `gl_type` as `system_gles2` to use the Mali implement of the egl, it will crash in `display.cc(55)` at starting up, and the error msg seemed so be `EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW`, from the guideline in [cobalt guideline](http://cobalt.foo/starboard/porting.html), there need to set gl_typeto support egl, but it does not works,  so is there any other things which need to be done to support egl?

```
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.5.3 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2001-2010  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------
[0101/001609:ERROR:user_log.cc(32)] Not implemented reached in static bool base::UserLog::IsRegistrationSupported()
[2531:969391044:WARNING:thread_set_name.cc(36)] Thread name "StorageManager SQL" was truncated to "StorageManager "
[0101/001609:FATAL:display.cc(55)] Check failed: 0x3000 == eglGetError() (12288 vs. 12299)

Caught signal: SIGABRT (6)
        <unknown> [0xb5acb4d8]
        <unknown> [0xb5acc8a4]
        SbSystemGetErrorString [0xbca1c]
        logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0x7f348]
        logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0x7f348]
        logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0x7f348]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the value returned by `SbWindowGetPlatformHandle()` is compatible with the EGL implementation on your system. You can look in `EGL/eglplatform.h` to see what `EGLNativeWindowType` is typedef'd to for your platform. On Raspberry Pi, for instance, it's a pointer to a [`EGL_DISPMANX_WINDOW_T`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/opt/vc/include/EGL/eglplatform.h) that contains several fields.

Comment: yeah, it is the problem as you said, after making the type compatiable with the platform, then it's works, thanks so much for your kind help!